# How to calculate $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{n}} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to prove that the sum $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{n}} $ converge, and to calculate it.

Proving convergence was the easy part, I used the root test in order to do it.

But I have no idea how to calculate it.

Any ideas will be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just a $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a}{b^n}$ problem right?

Comment: simly use the fact that is a geometric series (you can take $x^2$ out of the series)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x\neq0$ we have $0<\frac{1}{1+x^2}<1$. Then $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^n}\\=x^2\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1+x^2}}=1+x^2$$

Comment: oh, I let those x^2 confuse me. Thanks !